# Conceptual difference between join() using nested for loop and generator expression

Tags: python, generator-expression

Recently, I have been trying to join elements present inside an array, which itself is present inside an another array **(say array1)**. Using generator expressions I was able to join the elements successfully. The code looks like this:

```
array1=[[0,2],[1,1,1],[3,11,1],[2,4,0]]    #Driver list
result=[]                               #Array where the **value** gets appended 
for i in x:                             #for loop to iterate inside array1
    value='.'join(str(j) for j in i)    #join() using generator expression
    result.append(value)
print(result)
```

The output we get is:

```
['0.2', '1.1.1', '3.11.1', '2.4.0']
```

I tried to code the same using nested for loop, and before running the program, I thought, it should provide the same output as above.

:The code involving `join()` using `nested for loop` is:

```
 array1=[[0,2],[1,1,1],[3,11,1],[2,4,0]]    #Driver list
 result=[]
 for i in array1:                        #Nested for loop
     for j in i:
        value='.'.join(str(j))
        result.append(value)
 print(result)
```

But to my surprise, the output I got was

```
['0', '2', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1.1', '1', '2', '4', '0']
```

I copied both the codes and ran it in ***python visualize*** to get an idea about the values of `i` and `j`, but no clarity was obtained. According to my thinking, both the codes must work in same way.

Is there any conceptual difference between the codes I have written? If so, what options do I have, to make the second code ( join() using nested for loop ) to produce the same output as in the first case.

Comment: In your second example, ```j``` is an item within the sub-array. It has a length of 1, joining it does nothing. You are just converting each item in the sub-arrays to a string and then appending them to another list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join is taking a list and turning it into a string with the string, in the beginning, separates between values in the list so if you give join just int or string it will return the same as doing str(value).
for example:

".".join(5) will give: "5"

".".join([5,8]) will give: "5.8"

So Yes, In the first option, you use one for loop so you get into i: [0,2], [1,1,1] ... and in the join, you do something called list comprehension so it stays the same list but in the second solution you get into j: 0,2,1,1,1 .... and as we mentioned before there is a difference between join that get value as parameter and not list so that is the reason you get this output, I would recommend you to print i and j to understand what you put in the join as parameter:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just say now whether my understanding is correct or not.. In the first case, ```j``` iterates through all the values in ```i``` and it presents itself as a list. For eg. [1,1,1]. Now the join() iterates through [1,1,1] and produces the output...Am i right?

Comment: Yap :), tell me if you have more questions